# How to change separately speed of pointer for mouse / touchpad?

Tags: mouse, system-settings

Recently I've connected USB mouse to my laptop with touchpad. In Mouse and Touchpad settings section I see only touchpad pointer speed.

Now mouse moves a pointer too fast. How do I change that?

---

14.04 Mouse and Touchpad settings screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
xinput set-prop "Logitech USB Optical Mouse" "Device Accel Constant Deceleration" 5
xinput set-prop "Logitech USB Optical Mouse" "Device Accel Velocity Scaling" 1
```

Comment: xinput alone should tell what mouse you have but not near my ubuntu box right now.

Comment: I have a script like this run at startup with Startup Applications for my mouse.

Comment: String device and type identification didn't work, but two commands `xinput` and `xinput list-props [device_id]` told me what to type. I had `Velocity Scaling` `10` and changed it to `4`. Great, thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

i'm assuming you are using 14.04..
  the mouse/touchpad inside system settings
   and each have their own sensitivity level sliders.

i've not tried using anything other than my built-in touchpad. 
but since the new release has settings for each, why not disable your touchpad via function keys,  and then see if changing the settings have any effect on the external mouse.
if not then you may need a newer driver for the mouse to support selective sensitivity.

Comment: 1) Please take a look at the edited Question. I do not see the slider for 'external' mouse sensitivity. The first slider is for double-click speed. 2) I don't have function keys for disabling the touchpad. 3) It does not seem to me that touchpad settings affect 'external' mouse.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Find the xinput {id} for mouse/touchpad.(For me, {id}=16)

$ xinput

> xinput

(2) Find corresponding {property_id} for "Device Accel Constant Deceleration (271)". In my case, {property_id} =271.

$ xinput --list-props {id}

> xinput --list-props 16

(3) Set the property.

$ xinput --set-prop {id} {property_id} 2.5

> xinput --set-prop 16 271 2.5